# Find center of cell where a given point resides in an isometric grid

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have an isometric grid like the one below, centered in $(0,0)$, where $w = 2h$.

[image]

Given a random point $P = (x,y)$, how can I evaluate the center of the region $P$ is in? For simplicity, one can suppose $w = 64$ and $h = 32$.

If $P$ resides in the intersection of 2 or more regions, the center of any of them is fine.

---

I thought about listing all the centers of the regions up to a certain distance of $P$ but didn't know how to decide which of the regions it is inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we number each cell using integers $u$ and $v$, so that the cell marked $(0,0)$ corresponds to $u = 0$, $v = 0$, with $u$ increasing down right, and $v$ increasing up right, with the horizontal diagonal of each cell being $w$ wide, and vertical diagonal $h$ tall, we have a mapping
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
x & = \displaystyle \frac{w}{2} ( u + v ) \\
y & = \displaystyle \frac{h}{2} ( u - v ) \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
In other words, when $u$ increases by one, $x$ increases by half $w$ and $y$ increases by half $h$. When $v$ increases by one, $x$ increases by half $w$ but $y$ decreases by half $w$. When both increase by one, $x$ increases by $w$ but $y$ stays the same.

The inverse of $\eqref{G1}$ is
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
u & = \displaystyle \frac{h x + w y}{h w} = \frac{x}{w} + \frac{y}{h} \\
v & = \displaystyle \frac{h x - w y}{h w} = \frac{x}{w} - \frac{y}{h} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{2}\label{G2}$$

If we look at the $u$ and $v$ coordinates where the lines are drawn – in other words, where in fractional $u$ and $v$ coordinates the boundaries of each cell is –, we notice that they are drawn midway between integer $u$ or $v$, i.e. at $k + \frac{1}{2}$ for integer $k$ ($k \in \mathbb{Z}$).

This means that if you round the above $u$ and $v$ to nearest integer (`round(u)` and `round(v)` in many programming languages; $\lfloor u \rceil$ and $\lfloor v \rceil$ in mathematical notation), you get the exact cell number.  In other words, for integer $u$ and $v$, use
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
u & = \displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{h x + w y}{h w} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{w} + \frac{y}{h} \right\rceil \\
v & = \displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{h x - w y}{h w} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{w} - \frac{y}{h} \right\rceil \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{3}\label{G3}$$
In languages like Python where `round()` rounds halfway to even (or odd), you might wish to use `ceil(0.5 + number)` instead, so that halfway is rounded up (towards positive infinity), to get more uniform cell sizes (for small $w$ and/or $h$, especially).